# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'url''

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, solr, urllib2, urllib3

I am trying to access Solr using urllib2 as instaructed here: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/using-python.html using urllib

but running into error `raise URLError(err) urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'the_dns-for-lb'`

The cert exist in AWS ACM and there is custom auth, can someone guide me how to establish connection?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
connection = urlopen('https://dns-for-lb/solr/design').read()
response = eval(connection.read())
```

tried:
[Using urllib gives SSL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068772/using-urllib-gives-ssl-error)
[Using urllib gives SSL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068772/using-urllib-gives-ssl-error)
[pip install fails with "connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)